# Double click to enter current date/time in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to VBA and have the following code. When double clicking the first date box it works, but gives an error variable not defined for the second date box. Please advise?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private Sub CALL1_DATE__DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
CALL1_DATE_ = Now()
End Sub
Private Sub CALL2_DATE_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
CALL2_DATE_ = Now()
End Sub
```

Comment: When you run Debug \ Compile in VBA IDE (which you should do after every code change), does an error raise? It should since both variables are declared without `Dim` while `Option Explicit` is set.

Comment: One thing I spot is that there are 2 "_" here: `CALL1_DATE__DblClick`, but only 1 "_" here: `CALL2_DATE_DblClick`. So I _assume_ that perhaps `CALL2_DATE_ = Now()` should be `CALL2_DATE = Now()`

Answer (score 1):

Consider several best practices for VBA programming which you partially do:

1. Before actually running any subroutines or functions, always run `Debug \ Compile` on menu bar of VBA's IDE after making code changes. This will force you to handle all syntax or compile errors (i.e., all but runtime errors).
2. Like you already do, set `Option Explicit` at the top of code module. This forces programmers to declare every variable or object before use with `Dim` calls and avoid any side effects in runtime of code.
3. Related to above, use `Dim` for every named object to define its scope and type.

   ```
   Private Sub CALL1_DATE__DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
        Dim CALL1_DATE_ As Date

        CALL1_DATE_ = Now()
   End Sub

   Private Sub CALL2_DATE_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
        Dim CALL2_DATE_ As Date

        CALL2_DATE_ = Now()
   End Sub
   ```

   Alternatively you can set them as private or public variables outside the subroutines at the top of code module:

   ```
   Option Compare Database
   Option Explicit

   Private CALL1_DATE_ As Date         ' SAME AS: Dim CALL1_DATE_ As Date
   Private CALL2_DATE_ As Date         ' SAME AS: Dim CALL2_DATE_ As Date

   Private Sub CALL1_DATE__DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
        CALL1_DATE_ = Now()
   End Sub

   Private Sub CALL2_DATE_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
        CALL2_DATE_ = Now()
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Parfait nailed it. Go with this. I personally recommend the second suggestion! :)

Comment: Thanks @wakgtech! OP may be confusing VBA functions with subroutines with a return of same named object. Even correcting the underscores that Hel O'Ween comments above, code does compile without `Dim` but fails at runtime.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking time to review.

Comment: When I try the first suggestion nothing happens on double clicking the date box. When I try the second suggestion it gives an error message: member already exists in object module from which this object module derives

Comment: If I add the first bit of original code to for the first date box "CALL1_DATE", it works perfectly, it was only when I added the code for the second date box "CALL2_DATE", that this one did not work. The problem seems to be the switch over to the second group of code for "CALL2_DATE"

Comment: If I revert back to the original code and run debug, it says "compile error: expected:.", could I be missing a "." somewhere?

Comment: Nothing is supposed to happen as you do nothing with those variables but assign values. As for other error, I cannot reproduce your issue. I tested above by creating two buttons, *CALL1_DATE* and *CALL2_DATE* on an **empty** form with DblClick events as coded. Carefully check the name of your controls and see if other controls/objects or variables are not facing name collision.